# select with join using a standard php function

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to use a php function to select data from a database, Im using a "standard" php function:

```
 function select($table, $where, $other=''){
        try{
            $a = array();
            $w = "";
            $other=" ".$other;
            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                $w .= " and " .$key. " like :".$key;
                $a[":".$key] = $value;
            }
            $stmt = $this->bd->prepare("select * from ".$table." where 1=1 ". $w.$other); 
            $stmt->execute($a);
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($rows)<=0){
                $reponse["statut"] = "warning";
                $reponse["message"] = "no data found.";
            }else{
                $reponse["statut"] = "Success";
                $reponse["message"] = "Success";
            }
                $reponse["data"] = $rows;

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $reponse["statut"] = "Error";
            $reponse["message"] = 'selection failed: ' .$e->getMessage();
            $reponse["data"] = null;
        }
        return $reponse;
    }
```

The function works satisfyingly I faced problems only when I aimed to use a join and selecting from two tables.
say we have these two tables:

---

- id-cat  | cat-name |

  ---
- 1       | aaaaaa   |
- 2       | aaadda   |
- 3       | saaaca   |
- 4       | ahhaaa   |
- ---

and

---

- id-cat  | sub-cat  |
- 1       | 2   |
- 1       | 3   |
- 1       | 4   |
- 2       | 3   |
- 2       | 4   |

  ---

How to select the a category's subs name with given id-cat using MY FUNCTION ??

Comment: I think about changing the function since no answer is provided..

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple LEFT JOIN to the second table, using the column that exists in both tables.

```
$stmt = $this->bd->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM $table
                            LEFT JOIN $table2 USING id-cat
                            WHERE 1=1 ". $w.$other);
```

Comment: yes this would work but Im actually looking for a way to customize my function so it can handle many join tables & many join field !!